# Unable to resolve Undefined reference

Tags: c++, templates

I am having an issue in my function template whereby I am trying to instantiate my function in `Functions.cpp`. But having done that, it gives me a compilation error. Below is the error that I've got. If anyone is able to assist, would greatly appreciate it! Thanks!

**Error**

```
Functions.cpp:81:15: error: template-id ‘remove<int>’ for ‘int 
CS150::remove(int*, int*, int*)’ does n template declaration
template int remove<int>(int *first, int*last,  int* val);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~

Functions.cpp:56:5: note: candidate is: template<class T> T* 
CS150::remove(T*, T*, T*)

T* remove(T *first, T *last,  T* val)
   ^~~~~~
```

**Function.cpp**

```
template <typename T> 
T* remove(T *first, T *last,  T* val)
{
    T result = first;
    while (first!=last) 
    {
        if (!(*first == val)) 
        {
        *result = *first;
        ++result;
        }
        ++first;
    }
    return result;
}
template int remove<int>(int *first, int*last,  int* val);
```

**Functions.h**

```
template <typename T> 
T* remove(T *first, T *last, const T& val);
```

**driver file**

```
static void TestRemove1(void)
{
    cout << "***** Remove1 *****" << endl;
    int i1[] = { 5, -7, 4, 10, -21, 15, 9 };
    int size = sizeof(i1) / sizeof(int);
    CS150::display(i1, i1 + size);
    int item = -1;
    int * newend = CS150::remove(i1, i1 + size, item);
    cout << "remove " << item << ", new list: ";
    CS150::display(i1, newend);
}

static void TestRemove2(void)
{
    cout << "***** Remove2 *****" << endl;
    int i1[] = {5, -7, 4, 10, -7, 15, 9};

    int size = sizeof(i1) / sizeof(int);
    CS150::display(i1, i1 + size);
    int item = -7;
    int *newend = CS150::remove(i1, i1 + size,  item);
    cout << "remove " << item << ", new list: ";
    CS150::display(i1, newend);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `template` keyword. The following may work (I'm still not sure why you need this line at all):

```
int remove<int>(int *first, int*last,  int* val);
```

By writing `remove<int>` you instantiate your template, so it's not a template anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your template function signature says it returns `T*` but your function definition and instantiation return `T` (`int`). You need to make them match.